# ASP.NET, reference a local resource files from a class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, webforms

I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around how the resources work in an ASP.NET project. In my solution I have 2 projects:

1. A Website project that contains an App_GlobalResources folder where most of my resources reside (build action: "content").
2. A utility project, compiled as class library (that the website references), where I need another set of resources (called "ExceptionMessages" hereafter).

*Nota: each project uses its own resources, there is no cross linking involved here.*

I added a new resource directly in my second project (both as "content" or "embeded resource") and tried to access it via `ExceptionMessages.Tag`. Intellisense is happy about it and correctly suggests the Tag but I get the following error at runtime:

> "Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "Resources.ExceptionMessages.resources" was correctly embedded or
>   linked into assembly "App_GlobalResources.lqgd5zqy" at compile time,
>   or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed."

Somehow, I don't understand why the webserver is looking for the resource in the App_GlobalResources instead of directly in the assembly where it is used... or how I could go around this in a clean way. Any hint or idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes the class library assembly is signed.

Comment: Well, __It works on my computer__. Even with an unsigned lib. Your question is seriously short on details. How are the resources accessed, file structure, ...

Comment: is your resource file other than neutral culture?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: That's odd. I did not precise that the first project references the second one... could that play a role in there?

Comment: @ImranRizvi: right now it is only the neutral one ; of course I'd like to localize it at some point.

Comment: hmm, check if the link helps you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058441/could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutra

Comment: @ImranRizvi: the designer.cs file specifies `ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Resources.ExceptionMessages", global::System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));` as stated in the question you linked. But when I set the last part to  `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` the assembly name changes in the error message but the message is there still...