# Getting error while running ASP.NET application after installing AjaxControlToolkit Nuget package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

I'm getting following error:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.NET4.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "AjaxControlToolkit" at compile time,
>   or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you please provide details on how to reproduce this error? Have you tried [existing solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058441/could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutra)?

Comment: @RowanFreeman Thanks for suggestion. I have resolved the issue by adding                                               <asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:scriptmanager>