# Error when trying to add ajax control toolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a problem when i try to add ajax control toolkit:

Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.NET4.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "AjaxControlToolkit" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.NET4.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "AjaxControlToolkit" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: You could have given better question title

Comment: what have you tried?  have you googled the error? what are you trying to do?

a quick serach indicates this question might be what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058441/could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutra

several good answers there

Comment: Did you add ScriptManager in your page. Post your code for better understanding

Comment: [Check this link for your error](https://developerhelpers.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/ajax-toolkit-error-could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutral-culture-make-sure-ajaxcontroltoolkit-properties-resources-net4-resources-was-correctly-embed/)

Answer (score 9):

You need to add ScriptManager in your page from ajax extensions or from ajax control list.