# Global Resource File asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, multilingual, app-globalresources

Okay below image is explaining everything.

[image: My Issue]

i have also included the code for further explanation.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo(Session("Lang").ToString())
Dim rm As ResourceManager = New ResourceManager("TodayTimesheet.App_GlobalResources.Lang", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
Dim ci As CultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
btnSubmit.Text = rm.GetString("Add", ci)
```

Error message:

> An exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "TodayTimesheet.App_GlobalResources.Lang.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "TodayTimesheet" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058441/could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind ...

I have fixed the issue on my own by replacing the following line

```
 Dim rm As ResourceManager = New ResourceManager("TodayTimesheet.Lang", System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("TodayTimesheet"))
```