# Not able to add Resx file in VS Web Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, resx

First time ever I am using Resx file. So below steps I did till now.

1. Created empty Asp.net Solution.
2. Added a Resx file with basic name value content.
3. Add a web page and in code behind wrote below code:

   `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("UsingRESX.Resource1",
   Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
               String strWebsite = rm.GetString("Website", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); // here I get the exception
               String strName = rm.GetString("Name");
               form1.InnerText = "Website: " + strWebsite + "--Name: " + strName;
           }`

But when I run the code I get exception as :

```
   Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified
 culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "UsingRESX.Resource1.resources"
 was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "WebApplication1" at compile 
time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
```

Tutorial I followed for this exercise:
[Read Resx FIle](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/65794e/how-to-read-resx-file-in-c-sharp/)

SO solution that I tried:
[SO Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058441/could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutra)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`?

Comment: I am silly guy. I need to do <MyProjectName.ResourcefileName> I used the project name that was in the sample I was looking into. I just changed it to correct project name and it all worked.

Comment: My projectname is webapplication1, but I used something else in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

and set a breakpoint.  This will list all the embedded resources. Make sure you have the correct name.  Sometimes the resource paths aren't entirely obvious.

Comment: Adding this line, throws error. "assembly" is not recognized.

Comment: I see this as output "WebApplication1.Resource1.resources" . Is this correct?

Comment: It just has one entry.

Comment: I have added the screenshot in the original question Kindly see it once. Thanks!

Comment: Added my VS folder structure too in original question.

Comment: I am silly guy. I need to do <MyProjectName.ResourcefileName> I used the project name that was in the sample I was looking into. I just changed it to correct project name and it all worked.

Comment: glad you got it sorted. please mark this as the answer if it solved your issue.  Thank you.