# MissingManifestResourceException while accessing resx file

Tags: c#, .net, resx

I am getting `MissingManifestResourceException` exception when trying to access the resx file.

I have one code snippet which works fine and I have another one which does not work. I am not sure what is going on here.

**Working Snippet**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Keep an Eye on the first parameter I have passed, it has ".Lang" in it 
    var rm = new ResourceManager("ConsoleApp1.App_GlobalResources.Lang", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    var ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    var a = rm.GetString("Name", ci);
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
```

**Non Working Snippet:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Keep an eye on first parameter no ".Lang" here.
    var rm = new ResourceManager("ConsoleApp1.App_GlobalResources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    var ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    var a = rm.GetString("Name", ci);
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
```

My Solution Structure:

[image]

Property of Lang.en-US file (Works Fine):

[image]

Property of en-US file (DO NOT Work):

[image]

**Question 1:** Why does Lang.en-US does not generate any .CS file, even then IT WORKS

**Question 2:** Why does a basic bare en-US.resx creates a .CS file and still does not work.

Link I looked into: [SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058441/could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutra)

Pic 1:

[image]

Pic 2:

[image]

Comment: Mind publishing the Lang.en-US.resx file ?

Comment: What do you mean by publishing? I am beginner kindly guide me. And by the way that file is working fine.

Comment: @OrelEraki: FIle with NO .Lang extension is problemtic

Comment: I'm pretty sure that isn't the problem, but take a picture of `Lang.en-US.resx` and `en-US.resx`

Comment: @OrelEraki: Pic added in the edit. Can you kindly take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Working example works as follow.

1. ResourceManager loads "Lang" as his virtual file prefix set.
2. GetString(Key, Culture) - tries to look for the correct culture, if it doesn't find one, then it will fallback to none culture file. e.g: for 'en-US' it will try to find `Lang.en-US.resx` and will default to `Lang.resx`

Your Non-Working example doesn't work, because you don't give it a virtual file prefix, but a folder path.

**Solution:**
One Ideal situation, is using your Working with the following multiple language files.

Language folder (i.e: App_GlobalResources [bad name])

- Lang.resx: default for non existing cultures files
- Lang.en-US.resx: en-US culture
- Lang.he.resx: he culture
- You can see the gist

**Code:**

```
var rm = new ResourceManager("ConsoleApp1.App_GlobalResources.Lang", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. Can you kindly tell me why first one works then?

Comment: Ideally that should also give error right? The .Lang one: why it works

Comment: I am sorry, I will repeat my question again, I want to know why `var rm = new ResourceManager("ConsoleApp1.App_GlobalResources.Lang", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());` code snippet works fine.

Comment: And note that I have kept just one `Lang.en-US.resx` file in my solution, thats it. I have deleted other files

Comment: As per you I have not mentioned the Current thread here also, but stil it works, please guide me

Comment: In very simple terms, why my Code Snippet 1 is working fine for me? Can you kidnly take a look at code snippet one once. Please

Comment: I've added a better explanation.