# calledType.InvokeMember don't work. How to get value of resource?

Tags: c#, resources, resx, invokemember

I try to get a value of ressource.resx and I can't.

I do :

```
foreach (string certif in ContactCertifications)
{
    Type calledType = Type.GetType("TestNamespace.Resources");            

    String s = (String)calledType.InvokeMember(certif,BindingFlags.InvokeMethod 

    | BindingFlags.Public |BindingFlags.Static,null,null,null);                                       }
```

certif = "PRG_CARTV"

calledType is : {Name = "Resources" FullName = "TestNamespace.Resources"}
and when I'm in line "String s = (String)calledType" I have an error : "Method 'TestNamespace.Resources.PRG_CARTV' not found."

And when I have  `String s = TestNamespace.Resources.PRG_CARTV;` it's work, so I don't understend..

When I do simply :

```
var myManager = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources));
var myString = myManager.GetString("PRG_CARTV");
```

it's doesn't work, I have a error : "Can not find appropriate resources for the specified culture or neutral culture. Make sure \ "TestNamespace.Ressources.resources \" has been correctly embedded or linked in the assembly ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems here:

1) Getting the value of a resource via reflection, I tried this one and worked:

```
String s = (String) calledType.InvokeMember(certif, BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, null, null, null);
```

Note the binding flags that changed: `BindingFlags.GetProperty` instead of `BindingFlags.InvokeMethod` and `BindingFlags.NonPublic` instead of `BindingFlags.Public`

2) Issue with the ResourceManager. I myself would try to recreate the Resources.resx again. If you want to investigate further check similar problems here in StackOverflow, for example: [Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058441/could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutra)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response but this solution don't work either for me. :/ 
I have : calledType = {Name = "Resources" FullName = "TestNamespace.Resources"} and then an exception : 

"Method 'TestNamespace.Resources.PRG_CARTV' not found"

But I will look link that you sent me.

Comment: O, I found how to get this value with RessourceManager, thx!



var myManager = new ResourceManager(typeof(ConsoleApp1.Properties.Ressources));
var myString = myManager.GetString("PRG_CARTV");