# Creating own code for Resource is throwing error - unable to get data for the specified or neutral culture

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, resx, culture

I keep getting a culture error and I'm unable to resolve it. I've tried to iterate on the issue, previously raised a question that was closed and implemented various solutions without any success. Details of all tested solutions are mentioned at the end of the question. Here are my two files:

First file (main code):

```
using Properties;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace malt
{
    class Programs
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] med = Properties.Resources.med;
            Console.WriteLine(med);
        }
    }
}
```

Second file (Resources.cs in the same folder as Resources.resx):

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Resources;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;


namespace Properties
{
  internal sealed class Resources
  {
    private static ResourceManager resourceMan;
    public static CultureInfo resourceCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;


    internal Resources()
    {
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    internal static ResourceManager ResourceManager
    {
      get
      {
        if (Properties.Resources.resourceMan == null)
          Properties.Resources.resourceMan = new ResourceManager("Properties.Resources", typeof (Properties.Resources).Assembly);
        return Properties.Resources.resourceMan;
      }
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    internal static CultureInfo Culture
    {
      get => Properties.Resources.resourceCulture;
      set => Properties.Resources.resourceCulture = value;
    }

    internal static byte[] med => (byte[]) Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(nameof (med), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  }
}
```

Full error:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
> the neutral culture. Make sure that "Properties.Resources.resources"
> was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "madt" at compile time,
> or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
> signed.

---

### Note
I asked this question before, but although the address it directed was not a solution, it closed the question and did not reopen it even though I edited it. That's why I asked again :)

*List of things I've tried:*

- Before saying this link is an answer and closing the question [Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058441/could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutra):
- The Compilation Action property of my .resx file is Embedded and still not works
- Both of files are not including any special chars
- I've played too much time with "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture" in Resources.cs's `internal static byte[] med => (byte[]) Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(nameof (medus1), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` line
- I've also tried the answers to the previously asked questions but it didn't work
- I don't have a function like this in my code `ProblemAssembly.Support`. My problem is in `internal static byte[] med => (byte[]) Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(nameof (med), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` line. If you can adapt this please let me know
- My resx file's build action option is already Embedded Resource
- Already I don't have `Properties/Resources.designer.cs` file
- My resx file is already included in project
- I don't use .NET Core 3.0
- Tried to change CultureInfo type to public, private, internal but no one has been worked
- Tried to change project name
- If I use try catch for escaping from this error, my code will not work and nothing will be different

Comment: Main file name is different by project name and also not program.cs too

Comment: I have added an answer to this, but I'm still not certain what is the actual question - whether it is just "how to use resources in the application" or something more delicate like "using resource with selected culture only". So I've updated also your question - how it made the most sense. If you don't agree on that, please update it so it reflects actual state. :) And if you find my answer helping you with the issue, it would be great to "accept it as an answer" and/or "vote it up". Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are missing a point about "how this resource file should work". Developer is not ment to create and write this `Resources.cs` file himself, instead it should be automatically generated **whenever the actual resource change** (`resx` file).

That means: If you add new line/new file into `Resource1.resx` -> Visual Studio (or any other IDE) will invoke regeneration of that `Resources1.Designer.cs` by using the generator tool specified in the properties of the file. And this generator tool will modify existing `Resources1.Designer.cs` and append new C# code, that can be later used in the application.

I'm attaching screenshot about how it looks in Solution explorer (notice that the `Resource1.Designer.cs` is hidden under the `Resource1.resx` file, it must be expanded to be seen) + details of settings for `resx` file (it is marked as `Embedded resource` and have `ResXFileCodeGenerator` as a generator):

[image: Resources file]

To obtain the resources from the file, just grab it directly via generated code:

```cs
// The format for accessing is <nameOfFile>.<nameOfResourceWithinFile>
var myResource = Resource1.med;
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253291/discussion-on-answer-by-tatranskymedved-creating-own-code-for-resource-is-throwi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.